# How to add commas in numbers in a HTML table lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning component where i have created a table using HTML(tr & td). Everything i am able to achieve . However i am struck formatting the numbers inside the table.

As in the below table i want the numbers 137309 should be displayed as 1,37,709.(All the numbers to have commas accordingly).

[image]

Any suggestions in this regards is appreciated

Sample Code:

```
  <td class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right rowclass4">{!prod.F2Actuals} </td>
                        <td class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right rowclass4">{!prod.F1Actuals} </td>
                        <td class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right rowclass4"> {!prod.FActuals}</td>
                        <td class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered slds-border_left slds-border_right rowclass4">{!prod.FActualsYTD}  </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For currency cell, you could use the [`lightning:formattedNumber`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedNumber/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDecimalFormatting) base component to format the numbers as needed:

```
<lightning:formattedNumber value="{!prod.F2Actuals}"/>
```